# How to create a line output from a buffer instead of a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, line

[image]

I am looking to create a graduated line buffer like in the image attached.  I was wondering if there was a direct tool to do this?  I can do it in a few steps, but that may take too long.

I also tried using copy parallel, but it doesn't work as the lines get distorted and don't go the entire length from red line to red line.

Maybe there is a tool in spatial analyst that I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a combination of the [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001p000000) tool and then the [Polygon to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003t000000) tool, this should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Also if you just need it to visually look like a line you could just change the polygon fill to hollow and make the outline a dashed line.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the trace tool with an offset (if you are in an edit session). For the offset, press "o" when you are drawing.